# Only on Firefox: finally is not a function | promise overwritten by package

Tags: javascript, firefox, es6-promise

> Note: The issue is resolved [here](https://github.com/algolia/places/pull/726). It was a problem from a package.

I just tested my website on Firefox 64.x and saw the error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "ic.all(...).then(...).catch(...).finally is not a function"
    Vl https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js:1:1098907
    Promise http://9fcca2ff.eu.ngrok.io/js/vendor.js:183682:7
    Vl https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js:1:1098761
    i2svg https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js:1:1107850
    Pl https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js:1:1110939
    <anonymous> https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js:1:1111071
```

I don't really understand why I have this problem since I'm using Firefox 64.x and it should have finally as default.

To test if I type this in the console:

```
Promise.resolve(42).finally(() => console.log('jo'));
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Promise.resolve(...).finally is not a function[Learn More]

The weird part is, that it is only on my website. If I go to other websites and type this inside the console it always works...

As side infos for my project, I'm using:

> -webpack 3.x
>   -vue 2.6.0
>   -node 10.5.0
>   -npm 6.5.0
>   -laravel 5.7.x

for babelrc I'm only using:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

and for polyfill I'm using

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

The first google query gave me this issue: [Promise.prototype.finally() broken in Firefox](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2012), but I'm not using Vue-cli and all my packages are on the last update...

The second query in google gave me this: [Firefox Promise - getting finally is not a function?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/am5yeh/firefox_promise_getting_finally_is_not_a_function/) but it links back to the first issue, saying it's an issue of `core.js`. But I'm not good enough to understand how I can fix it.

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1:**

I found the source of the issue. [Algolia Place](https://github.com/algolia/places) overwrites `finally`, you can even go to their [demo page](https://community.algolia.com/places/) and you will notice it, when you type `Promise.toSource()`

My guess is, that their [package.json](https://github.com/algolia/places/blob/master/package.json) is not used correctly, since `"@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"` is listed as dependencies and I guess is forcing my webpage to use it as well and overwriting `finally`?

**Edit 2:**

Opened an issue on github https://github.com/algolia/places/issues/725

Comment: It works natively in Firefox for me (version 65).

Comment: Are you sure you're not importing some Promise library that overwrites the native code?

Comment: @Pointy that's a tricky question, I just removed the polyfill.io but had the same issue. Does it help if I post my package.json? Because I cannot find any other promise library...

Comment: Do you get "[native code]" when you do `Promise.toSource()`?

Comment: @trincot actually not, I get: `"(function Promise(executor) {
    anInstance(this, $Promise, PROMISE, '_h');
    aFunction(executor);
    Internal.call(this);
    try {
      executor(ctx($resolve, this, 1), ctx($reject, this, 1));
    } catch (err) {
      $reject.call(this, err);
    }
  })"`

Comment: That means something's clobbering the native version.

Comment: That is proof that you are not dealing with the native Promise, but with a polyfill.

Comment: @trincot & pointy, okay trying to find it out

Comment: @Shadrix If you remove the polyfill and still getting error that means some library in your bundle is overriding that.

Comment: i think you rewrite Promise class on polyfill wich doesn't support this method, you can try Bluebird library, maybe it's fix it.

Comment: @VadimHulevich I installed Laravel completely fresh and `finally` works there. Now I'm trying to reduce my page to a mininum to find the problem that overwrites my polyfill. When I found the root cause, I'm going to post it here of course.

Comment: @Pointy I edited my post at the bottom. I found the issue, but not sure at which part the promise is overwritten. My guess is because of `@babel/polyfill` in dependencies.